# non-static method cannot be referenced from a static method

Tags: java, arraylist

I'm trying to print my HighRights object but it wont let me..keeps saying non-static method cannot be referenced from a static method. I basically want it to print out all the values that were added ("AAA","AACCA"..etc).

```
import java.util.*; 

public class Ex8 {


    public void printHighUsers(ArrayList<SecurityRights> a){
       for(SecurityRights m: a)
        {
            if(m instanceof HighRights)
            {
                System.out.println(HighRights.getName());
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String [] a){
        ArrayList<SecurityRights> ma=new ArrayList<SecurityRights>();
        ma.add(new HighRights("AAA"));
        ma.add(new HighRights("AACCA"));
        ma.add(new HighRights("BB"));
        ma.add(new HighRights("AaaAA"));
        new Ex8().printHighUsers(ma);
    }
}
```

HighRights class:

```
public class HighRights extends SecurityRights
{
    private String name;

    public HighRights(String n){
    super(true);
    this.name = n;
   }

   public String getName(){
        return name;
    }


    public static void main(String[] a){

    HighRights s= new HighRights("Lisa");
    System.out.print(s.getName() +" "+s.getSecret());                
  }

}
```

Thank You.

Comment: Can you clarify how your question differs from the other questions with the same title in the sidebar? What is unclear about their solutions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In

```
System.out.println(HighRights.getName());
```

you're trying to invoke `getName()` statically, but it is not a `static` method.

What you want is

```
System.out.println(((HighRights) m).getName());
```

In other words, you need to cast your reference to `HighRights` so that the `getName()` method is accessible and invoke it on the reference, rather than statically.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i was looking for! I dont understand why we have HighRights in brackets followed by m).getName() :S

Comment: @user3364498 The `getName()` method seems to be declared in `HighRights`, but your `m` is a reference of type `SecurityRights`. If you want to invoke `getName()`, you need a reference of type `HighRights`. See the casting section in [this tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/subclasses.html).

Comment: So ((HighRights) m) casts the m reference to HighRights?

Comment: @user3364498 `(HighRights) m` is the cast. The additional parentheses around that are necessary because method invocation has higher precedence than casting. So `(HighRights) m.getName()` would try to cast the return value of `getName()`. In this case, that wouldn't even compile because `getName()` does not exist on the type `SecurityRights`.